# How to get the same result with https:// starting subdomains too?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, wildcard-subdomain

We need a dynamically setup wildcard subdomain URL rewrite to our WordPress `.htaccess`. After digging on the web I have a nice one, but it works only with the default `http://` and it doesn't work correctly with the default `https://`.

This method works now:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
```

with those pretags and it use the Affiliate WP default URL settings:

> https://docs.affiliatewp.com/article/50-affiliate-urls

I am using the following code to dynamically get the user's webpages to know who referred the current purchase for the webshop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This code above works if I open the following URL for example:

> http://johndoe.mydomain.com

It stays dynamic and it opens automatically with "https://" location.

But it doesn't work if I want to open this URL like for example:

> https://johndoe.mydomain.com

because it doesn't get the /sponsor/ rewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS issue is quite common, and it can be solved by wrting the below code into wp-config.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) && "https" == $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) {
    $_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried your suggestion out but, im sorry, it doesn't help. I know, that i need some extra codes into my .htaccess what configures this correct http request for https too!

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: I still need help, any ideas?